# blank react app after deploying on GitHub pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

My project was all good until I deployed it on GitHub pages ;( ... it's now showing a blank page and I tried looking into the same issue on StackOverflow, but they're not facing exactly as my issue, so I looked it up on youtube and tried some tutorials but no results still, so here I'm on StackOverflow again. I think the HashRouter is causing me issues if I'm not mistaken. or, I followed multiple solutions and I'm lost now.
so... here is my GitHub repo:
https://github.com/AndiiCodes/test1

deployment:
https://andiicodes.github.io/test1/

Comment: The console shows TypeError: a.unstable_createSyncRoot is not a function . Does that mean anything to you?

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea why it is happening. but there could be other ways to deploy your react-app for free such as Netlify and Vercel. I would humbly request you to choose vercel since it has variety of options.